# How to get PID of current rake task?

Tags: ruby, shell, rake

I'm putting in a reaper line into a rake task to kill some additionally spawned ruby tasks as they somehow creep up on occasion.

```
system "ps aux | grep 'namespace:taskname' | grep ruby | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9; echo 'Reaped old namespace:taskname processes.'"
```

I'd like to add `grep -v $PID_OF_CURRENT_TASK` in that just to be sure I don't kill the current task that's running as well.

How do I get that PID?

Comment: You may be able to replace the whole pipeline with a well-drafted call of `pkill` or `killall`, or at least replace the first part of this pipeline with `pgrep`. These commands are more secure and much more understandable to a reader.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You get the current PID in Ruby with `Process.pid`

Comment: There's also `$$` (which came from Perl which got it from `/bin/sh`).

Comment: I forgot about that. It is more cryptic, but simpler. If you `require "english"`, then there is also `$PID` or something like that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the difference between `pid`, `ppid`, `uid`, `euid`, `gid` and `egid`?

Comment: @JoshPinter: `pid` is the ID of the running process, `ppid` is the PID of the parent process (for example, in the command `ruby test.rb` in bash, that would be bash), `gid` is group id, or the UNIX group as which the process is running, `uid` is the UNIX user id under which the process is running (this determines privileges), and `euid` and `egid` are *effective* user and group IDs (which have something to do with running things as root on UNIX that I'll admit I've never really completely understood).

Comment: Well, that was a fantastic answer @Linuxios. And in 2 1/2 minutes no less. Thanks!

Comment: @Linuxios I didn't think I'd get an answer at all, let alone that quickly, so I posted a question for it. Not sure if you want to post your comment on there as an answer. Probably would help others in the future.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30493424/what-is-the-difference-between-a-process-pid-ppid-uid-euid-gid-and-egid

Comment: @JoshPinter: writing an answer now.

Comment: @Linuxios `euid` and `egid` determine the privileges, not `uid` or `gid`. They differ when you use `sudo` or other s-bit programs (`ls -l /usr/bin/sudo`) or `seteuid` / `setegid`.

Comment: @hagello: Thanks. I'd had to take out my old Linux book for that one.